# DAX create column that references two columns and previous row

Tags: powerbi, dax

Example below is my table in PowerBI desktop. I am needing to edit (or create new) a column that refers to separate date columns along with previous rows. The datetime2 column is always a static date/time. I need to change the value in the "units" column to NULL when the datetime2 LESS THAN datetime1 AND datetime2 GREATER THAN **previous row** datetime1.

[image]

I have tried creating a new column with an If statement and using the EARLIER function but did not have any luck. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to:

```
units v2 = 
  var prevDT1 = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[datetimel]), FILTER('YourTable', [datetimel] < EARLIER([datetimel])))
  return IF(
    [datetime2] < [datetimel] && [datetime2] > prevDT1,
    BLANK(),
    [units]
  )
```